# How to enable/disable IPv6 on xrdp?

Tags: xrdp

> Linux rudy 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10
> UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

as far as I know:
lsb_release -a

> LSB
> Version:  core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Release: 20.04
> Codename: focal

Hi Community,

just wondering if there is available a comprehensive xrdp manual other than man xrdp/xrdp.ini/sesman and so on?
The XRDP service is listening on tcp6 and I do not know who is telling it to do so. The listen port is the default 3389 on 0.0.0.0

```
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3350                :::*                    LISTEN      60627/xrdp-sesman   
tcp6       0      0 :::3389                 :::*                    LISTEN      60638/xrdp
```

On the other hand, it is listening on 0.0.0.0: 3389. Are these related somehow? netstat listen on IPv6:3389 or xrdp status listen on 0.0.0.0 3389?

```
systemctl status xrdp
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-06-30 21:30:44 EDT; 14h ago
       Docs: man:xrdp(8)
             man:xrdp.ini(5)
   Main PID: 60638 (xrdp)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 6920)
     Memory: 1.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
             └─60638 /usr/sbin/xrdp

Jun 30 21:30:43 rudy xrdp[60637]: (60637)(139653515220800)[INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
Jun 30 21:30:43 rudy xrdp[60637]: (60637)(139653515220800)[INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
Jun 30 21:30:43 rudy xrdp[60637]: (60637)(139653515220800)[INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
Jun 30 21:30:43 rudy xrdp[60637]: (60637)(139653515220800)[DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
Jun 30 21:30:43 rudy systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Can't open PID file /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Jun 30 21:30:44 rudy systemd[1]: Started xrdp daemon.
Jun 30 21:30:45 rudy xrdp[60638]: (60638)(139653515220800)[INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 60638
Jun 30 21:30:45 rudy xrdp[60638]: (60638)(139653515220800)[INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
Jun 30 21:30:45 rudy xrdp[60638]: (60638)(139653515220800)[INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
Jun 30 21:30:45 rudy xrdp[60638]: (60638)(139653515220800)[INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
```

which conf file these following xrdp options can be changed and what is the syntax?
xrdp -v

```
xrdp 0.9.12
  A Remote Desktop Protocol Server.
  Copyright (C) 2004-2018 Jay Sorg, Neutrino Labs, and all contributors.
  See https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp for more information.

  Configure options:
      --enable-ipv6
      --enable-jpeg
      --enable-fuse
      --enable-rfxcodec
      --enable-opus
      --enable-painter
      --enable-vsock
      --build=x86_64-linux-gnu
      --prefix=/usr
      --includedir=${prefix}/include
      --mandir=${prefix}/share/man
      --infodir=${prefix}/share/info
      --sysconfdir=/etc
      --localstatedir=/var
      --disable-silent-rules
      --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      --disable-maintainer-mode
      --disable-dependency-tracking
      --with-socketdir=/run/xrdp/sockdir
      build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu
      CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/xrdp-GJgww4/xrdp-0.9.12=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security 
      LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed
      CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 
      PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/build/xrdp-GJgww4/xrdp-0.9.12/pkgconfig

  Compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

IPv6 is enabled system-wide:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0  
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
```

Comment: IMHO this is 20.04 LTS Focal, let me know please how you come up with Puppy Linux and I will investigate.

Comment: I made a mistake and confused your machine name rudy with Puppy Linux Rudy. I am sorry.

Comment: no problem, hostname:rudy :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the installer script with the `-c` option. Execute these steps as a non-root user -

```
wget https://www.c-nergy.be/downloads/xRDP/xrdp-installer-1.3.zip
unzip xrdp-installer-1.3.zip 
chmod +x xrdp-installer-1.3.sh
./xrdp-installer-1.3.sh -c
```

This compiles with ipv6 disabled by default.

For complete details and more options check this https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=17175 or https://www.c-nergy.be/products.html for latest release.